# How to show tax and shipping costs in custom popup of jquery in Magento 2?

Tags: magento-2.2.5

I want to display tax amount, shipping amount , and total in custom jquery popup dialog and that should be visible in checkout page. I have added a button in checkout page on click of it a popup shows simple text. i want to display tax and ship amount. How can I do that?? 
can anyone help me to do that.

Comment: In current pop-up, you show simple text using html file ot phtml file?

Comment: It is HTML file

Comment: do you used to jquery code for this pop-up, right? which is currently into another file apart from html?

Comment: yes. that is modal-form.js file

Comment: I post answer, kindly check.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put code into your js file like this.

```
customfunction: function () {
    return "YOUR VALUE";
}
```

And into your html file you can call code like this.

```
<span class="yourclass" data-bind="text: customfunction()"></span>
```